Customization to allure report not working with cucumber
I am trying to customize my allure report and add a custom title heading,logo and test case id to each feature.
Any suggestions on how that can be acheived for cucumber with webdriver io
addLabel(name, value) - assign a custom label to test
addFeature(featureName) – assign features to test
addStory(storyName) – assign user story to test
These functions did not reflect anything
